# GoDaddy.com has sniped / stolen my domain name, what to do against this?

Tags: ip

I believe in 2018 it was I thought about registering an domain called creepixel.com. I used godaddy.com to see wether it was free or not and it was, now since then it is no longer. It has been registered by GoDaddy LLC... Even tho I never registered the IP they just sniped it and have it registered since then,

can I do anything against this?
*Also I have never really talked about the name or anything online and that IP is not really to be found anywhere so I cant image someone just randomly registering it and doing nothing with it.*

Comment: There is nothing you can do. Anyone can buy any domain name that is available (you are discussing a domain name, not an IP address).

Comment: They didn't "steal your IP".  They registered a domain name.  Anybody is allowed to do that.  (And if what you're seeking is *legal advice* or *representation* then that's *very* off-topic here.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this: https://www.wipo.int/amc/en/processes/process1/index.html

If you believe that GoDaddy registered the domain in bad faith (for example, by registering it with the intent to sell it to you at a higher price), you may be able to file a complaint with the World Intellectual Property Organization (WIPO). WIPO is an agency of the United Nations that handles disputes related to domain names.

But afaik it's not possible to take any legal action against GoDaddy for registering the domain, as they are within their rights to do so. It's always a good idea to register a domain name as soon as you have decided to use it, as domain names are often registered on a first-come, first-served basis.